# What is the difference between these two declarations of char?? Which one is correct?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main( )
{
char ch = '1' ;
printf ( "\n%d %c\n", ch, ch ) ;
return 0;
}

#include<stdio.h>
int main( )
{
char ch = 1 ;
printf ( "\n%d %c\n", ch, ch ) ;
return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between these two declarations of char?? Which one is correct??

Comment: Correct for what circumstance?

Comment: If you want both to give the same results, do `char ch=49` (because 49 is the ASCII code of '1')

Comment: A better way to learn about this is to run the code.  Or, a better way, would be to grab a `c` book and learn.

Comment: Note: there is no difference between the declarations, there is however a difference in their assignations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first piece of code assigns the character `'1'`, which has an ASCII value of 49.  Printing this as a character will yield `1`, while printing as a number will yield `49`.

The second piece of code assigns the value 1.  Printing it as a character yields an unprintable character with an implementation defined representation, while printing it as a number will yield `1`.

As for which is "correct", that depends on how you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The first one,

```
char c = '1';
```

is assigning the **ascii value of** [1 (*decimal 49*)](http://www.asciitable.com/) the second one,

```
char c = 1;
```

is assigning the **ascii value** [1 (*decimal 1, **SOH** "start of heading"*)](http://www.asciitable.com/).

So now, instead of asking which one is correct you get to decide, because both are valid, so which is correct depends on your intention.

Comment: Of course, the value of `'1'` is implementation-defined, and need not be ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ascii table and you should note that the char `'1' != 1`.

`'1'` in decimal value is `49`

The correct way is to use single quotes for the desired char like so

`char c = 'a'`